# Average of all values of a signal before they fall to a minimum

Tags: r

i have the following data: I need to take the average of all values till it falls to a minimum value as shown in the below image. I need to take average of all those values in the highlighted area (in red)

[image: problem illustration]

```html
Sample data of signal:
3
3.1
3
3.2
3
3.1
3.2
3
3
3.05
3.25
3.21
3.2
0.4
0.48
0.51
0.65
0.92
1.4
2
3.2
3
3.5
```

Comment: you need to first define both terms --- "before" and "minimum".

Answer (score 2):

You can find the `index` of the min value and subset values till that point and calculate `mean` like:

```
dat <- c(3, 3.1, 3, 3.2, 3, 3.1, 3.2, 3, 3, 3.05, 3.25, 3.21, 3.2, 0.4, 0.48, 0.51, 0.65, 0.92, 1.4, 2, 3.2, 3)
mean(dat[seq(max(which.min(dat)[1]-1, 1))])
[1] 3.100769
```

Or using `dplyr` as:

```
library(dplyr)
tibble(dat) %>%
  filter(row_number() < which.min(dat)) %>%
  summarise(mean = mean(dat))
# A tibble: 1 x 1
   mean
  <dbl>
1  3.10
```

Answer (score 0):

As we need to find the average of points before it falls to minimum value, create a logical vector (`v1 <= min(v1)`), get the cumulative max, convert the TRUE to NA and FALSE as 1, multiply with the points and get the `mean` with `na.rm` as TRUE

```
with(df1, mean(v1 * NA^(cummax(v1 <= min(v1))), na.rm = TRUE))
#[1] 3.100769
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(v1 = c(3, 3.1, 3, 3.2, 3, 3.1, 3.2, 3, 3, 3.05, 
 3.25, 3.21, 3.2, 0.4, 0.48, 0.51, 0.65, 0.92, 1.4, 2, 3.2, 3, 
  3.5)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -23L))
```

Comment: `NA^0` equals `1` is the stunner of the day!